# How to handover context between skills?

Tags: botframework

Currently I'm using Virtual Assistant in a C# solution and want to share context between some of my skills.

My idea is inside a skill change to another one, without going to the main bot. Basically, change skills while they are in the middle of a particular skill.

I saw something related to activity type handoff, but I'm not sure if it is for that situation.
It's possible to do it with BotFramework? If yes, what is the best approach to do that?

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/2456#issuecomment-544448161 and https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/2919 which are similar to what you are trying to do